# Which desktop recording software can be used to record also right click popups

Tags: video-recording, windows

Most of desktop recording software which I have tried - like sharex, obs studio - does not record everything - like right mouse click popup windows are missing from recording. At least for external applications, like Visual studio (For explorer right click popups are shown).

Do you know some desktop recording software, which can be used to do that one ? Or may be some driver/ option / etc...

Prefer open/ free software if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggling - I've used sharex - but before that one following thing needs to be done first.

Install TightVNC, register and start server.

- From settings enable loopback connection.
- Start TightVNC viewer
- From options select `'View only (Inputs ignored)'`.
- Connect to `localhost` - resize to half of display on one side, on another side select application to record.

You can also disable jpg compression / improve image for quality from VNC viewer settings.

Record normally using shareX, from VNC viewer connection (not from desktop software).